# What lies beyond the Möbius transform?

Tags: matrices, mobius-transformation

Consider the matrix

$\pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d} ^n$

This is isomorphic to the $n$ th iteration of the Möbius transform $\frac{a z + b}{c z + d}$ when the determinant is nonzero.

So I wonder what is the analogue isomorphism from a power of a $3 \times 3$ matrix to the iteration of an analytic function ?

I prefer to stay on the complex plane, so I am not so intrested in iterating functions defined for noncomplex numbers or more than 2 dimensions.

Comment: I find the edit removing the tags a bit strange ...

Comment: Why do you think there should be an analogue? Why should there even be an interpretation of a single $3\times3$ matrix in trems of functions on the complex plane?

Comment: Look Up Carleman matrix Greg. There you have a Taylor series associated with a Large matrix and the iterations of the Taylor iso to powers of the matrix.

Comment: Perhaps that information would be a helpful addition to the problem statement itself.

Comment: this is an interesting problem that i also have considered. it is definitely possible in my opinion to represent 3x3 matrix multiplication as composition of some class of complex functions but is very hard. The carlemann matrices of the mobius transformations reveal that the composition of 2x2 matrices is a very complicated algebraic process in carlemann space